# SKEmitterNode does not appear when running on device

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've been learning to use Spritekit in Swift these past few days using the Hacking With Swift Tutorials (Specifically Project 23). I was learning how to use SKEmitterNodes however they don't ever seem to appear. On runtime, the screen is a blank grey color that runs at 1 fps with 1 node on screen (supposedly the SKEmitterNode). I've tried changing the zPosition of the node but it doesn't seem to have any effect. Oddly, SKSpriteNodes and SKLabelNodes appear just fine. I cleaned the project and got rid of the "Hello World" in the GameScene.sks so I know its not anything from the default project. I've googled around extensively for an answer to this question but I've come up blank. Below is the offending code.

```
    import SpriteKit
    import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
         override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        //backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        if let starfield = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Starfield.sks") {
        starfield.position = CGPoint(x: 1024, y: 384)
        starfield.advanceSimulationTime(10)
        addChild(starfield)
        starfield.zPosition = 0
        }
```

edit: Alright guys I've solved it. It turns out Xcode doesn't like it when you try and add an SKEmitterNode exclusively programmatically (as opposed to SKSpriteNodes which it seems to handle fine). What I had to go and do was go into the GameScene.sks and manually add in my Starfield.sks file and then rename it to Starfield. Then I had to go inside the GameScene.swift file and hook the SKEmitterNode I had placed in the GameScene.sks editor by using this code inside the didMove function:

```
starfield = childNode(withName: "Starfield") as? 
SKEmitterNode
```

Now the new code looks like this:

```
var starfield: SKEmitterNode!

 override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    starfield = childNode(withName: "Starfield") as? 
    SKEmitterNode
    starfield?.position = CGPoint(x: 1024, y: 384)
    starfield?.advanceSimulationTime(10)
    starfield?.zPosition = -1
    }
```

I found this solution with the help of [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/158961/introduction-spritekit-scene-editor) tutorial

Comment: Do it after didMove,  iirc. There is a bug with doing it there

Comment: Also, dont add the file extension “sks”

Comment: I'm still very new to swift. Would I be putting it inside another function? Or would it just be inside the GameScene class? An example would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I looked up my notes,  the bug was/is in doing it in init, not the didMove. Ni Nisan Nijackle has the correct answer

Comment: Change the zPosition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code and trying it inside of Xcode, it seems it might be fine.... It runs fine on mine, but my particle emitter has a wide spread and barely visible...

Try changing the x position to the middle of the screen : 512.

It's a positioning of the emitter to a part of the screen that isn't to visible that's causing the problem.

You could also adjust the spread to make it visible from that position, but you said you are new and the most likely cause is the x position placement.

EDIT:

Ok it seems that you simply forgot to create the particles.
Just click File < New < File then click on SpriteKit Particle Emmitter, select a template you want, and finally make sure the name you gave the particle is the same as you named it in the code or vice versa.

Comment: Hm I gave that a shot and it did not fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: Show me the full Xcode project then, I might see how you adjusted the emitter node and stuff maybe then. You could try adjusting the emitter node, but you might not even have it running at all, try checking that first.

Comment: use 0,0 because that is the center of your screen

Comment: Here is the github repo for the project if you guys would like to take a look at it.    https://github.com/DoctorSpock/space-race

Comment: You just simply forgot to add the particles into the kit.  @SiobahnDevlin

Comment: Do you mean it wasn't in the xassets file or do you mean I didn't enable something? How would I go about fixing it?

Comment: Nooooooo... You don't put particle systems in there. You are supposed to treat those like your code, not like your photos. If you download the HackingWithSwift projects from GitHub, you will know why.

Comment: @NiNisanNijackle I will take a look and figure it out. Thank you for the help. Particle Systems == code not photos got it.

Comment: You want to treat it like code, they aren't the same at all, but you have to treat it like code.